# Finding letters in 2nd array element in 1st array element

Tags: javascript

Using javascript, I want to check if the string in the 1st array element contains all the letters of the 2nd array element. If so, return true. E.g. ["Mary", "Aarmy"] => true;
["hello", "hey"] => false.

I've tried the following code, which works for ["Mary", "Aarmy"] and ["voodoo", "no"], but doesn't work for ["hello", "hey"]. Appreciate any help, thanks!

```
function mutation(arr){
var str1 = arr.pop().toLowerCase();
 var str2 = arr.pop().toLowerCase();
 for(var i = 0; i < str2.length; i++){
  if(str1.indexOf(str2[i]) !== -1){
    return true;
  }
    else return false;
 }
}
```

Comment: Even with repetitions? Should this be true: `["aaaabbbb", "ab"]`?

Comment: Maybe you should change the order: `for(){if(str1.indexOf(str2[i])==-1) return false;} return true;`

Answer (score 4):

When you use `pop()` it'll return the last element in the array and not the first.

Also your `if else` is inside `for` and has a return statement. This does not let the `for` loop run completely and returns after the very first loop.

```js
function mutation(arr){
 var str2 = arr.pop().toLowerCase();
 var str1 = arr.pop().toLowerCase();
 console.log("str1: " + str1);
 console.log("str2: " + str2);
 for(var i = 0; i < str2.length; i++){
  if(str1.indexOf(str2[i]) === -1){
    return false;
  }
 }
 return true;
}

arr = ["hello", "hey"];
console.log(mutation(arr));

arr = ["Mary", "Aarmy"];
console.log(mutation(arr));
```

Answer (score 3):

Considering you can use [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), and [`lodash`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#isEqual), here is another solution:

```
const _ = require("lodash");

function mutation(arr) {

  var set1 = new Set(arr.pop().toLowerCase().split(''));
  var set2 = new Set(arr.pop().toLowerCase().split(''));

  return _.isEqual(set1, set2);

}

console.log(mutation(["Mary", "Aarmy"])); //true
console.log(mutation(["hello", "hey"])); //false
console.log(mutation(["voodoo", "no"])); //false
```

Check the working sample: https://jsfiddle.net/sayan751/3q8rtqy3/

Comment: isEqual looks at substrings?

Comment: @mplungjan not sure why you are asking about substrings, as here `isEqual` is comparing 2 sets.

Comment: They are not the same length - Did you run your code?

Comment: @mplungjan check the link for an working example: https://jsfiddle.net/sayan751/3q8rtqy3/

Answer (score 1):

Split and sort to speed up things - now only ONE comparison per set

```js
var arr = ["Mary", "Aarmy","hello", "hey", "voodoo", "no"]

function mutation(){
  var str1 = arr.pop().toLowerCase().split("").sort().join("");
  var str2 = arr.pop().toLowerCase().split("").sort().join("");
  return str1.indexOf(str2) !=-1;
} 
while (arr.length) console.log(arr[arr.length-2],mutation())
```

Comment: Can you explain how does it speed up things? Loop still has to run `str2.length` times.

Comment: No. It leaves the loop on the very first mismatch

Comment: Well if you look at my answer, there​ also you'll find loop breaks at first  mismatch. How does sorting makes a difference?

Comment: Sorting makes the loop unnecessary, but I did not implement that fully before. Now I did

Comment: Ok, got your logic. But it will not work when `arr = ["Maryaa", "Aarmy"]` (result will be false) even though both the strings have each others characters present.

Comment: He wants to know if all the letters of one word are contained in the other - if "contained" means one or more times then you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Recursively, just for sport. If you're dealing with long (>100 char) strings, this is risky, as it relies on stack space.

```js
const contains = function (a, b) {
  if (!b) return true;
  return a.indexOf(b[0]) !== -1 && contains(a, b.substring(1));
}

console.log(contains('mary', 'army')); // true
console.log(contains('hello', 'hey')); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

How could function return more than one value  ;) (line 6) And if second array has an array length of 3 it just checks the first arrays 3 elements. (line 4)

Answer (score 0):

```
function mutation(arr) {

  var set1 = arr[0].toLowerCase();
  var set2 = arr[1].split('');

  return set2.every(function(element, index, array){
      if(set1.indexOf(element.toLowerCase()) != -1)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
  });

}

console.log(mutation(["Mary", "Aarmy"]));   //return true
console.log(mutation(["hello", "hey"]));    //return false
console.log(mutation( ["voodoo", "no"]));   //return false
console.log(mutation( ["voodoo", "vo"]));   //return true
```